# Get basename from path in env variables using a Bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to get the basename from the env variable which I am doing like
example my basePath is basePath="x/y/z/t" and I want t, I am doing like:

```
$(basename $basePath)
```

but it is not helpful.

Similarly, I want to get the latest updated folder/file from that path which I am doing like:

```
$(basename $(ls -td '$basePath'/*/ | head -n1))
```

but this is also not helpful.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Do you understand what `$(...)` actually does?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
basePath="x/y/z/t"

# Find latest files modified in the last 24 Hours
find ${basePath/*\/} -type f -mtime +1
```

Comment: what about $(basename $(ls -td '$basePath'/*/ | head -n1))?

If I change $basePath to some hardcoded path then its fine, like this it wont take